# VUE: Как использовать два и больше атрибута ref?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<box category="one" tag="first"></box>
<box category="two" tag="second"></box>
```

В списке элементы содержат два свойства. Как определить элемент с нужными свойствами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<box v-for="(box,i) in [{category:'one', tag:'first'},{category:'two',tag:'second'}]" 
:key="i" :category="box.categody" 
:tag="box.tag" 
:ref="'box'+box.tag">
    {{box.ref}} 
</box>
```